# IEnumerable collection type, getting null values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With help from StackOverflow today, I have gotten my data layer constructed return data from my XML file to my Business Logic Layer.  However, I can't seem to get the data from my business objects layer.  The values are all null.  Sorry, to be such a newbie.... Thanks in advance.

Business logic layer:

```
public void getCustDetails(string customerId)
{                          
    DLGetCustomers obj = new DLGetCustomers();
    obj.getCustDetails(customerId);
    AccountDetails obj1 = new AccountDetails();
    FirstName = obj1.Fname;
    LastName = obj1.Lname;
    SSN = obj1.Ssn;
    Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(obj1.Dob);
    CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(obj1.Custid);
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Dob);
    Age = ts.Days / 365;
}
```

Data access layer:

```
public class AccountDetails
{
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public string Custid { get; set; }
} 

public IEnumerable<AccountDetails> getCustDetails(string customerId)
{
    //Pulls customer information for selected customer 
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
    var custRecords = from account in doc.Descendants("acct")
                      let acct = account.Element("acct")
                      where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                      select new AccountDetails
                      {
                          Fname = (string)account.Attribute("fname").Value,
                          Lname = (string)account.Attribute("lname").Value,
                          Ssn = (string)account.Attribute("ssn").Value,
                          Dob = (string)account.Attribute("dob").Value,
                          Custid = (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value
                      };                          

    return custRecords;
}
```

Comment: What values are null? How does your XML file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
AccountDetails obj1 = new AccountDetails();
```

Simply sets `obj1` to a new instance of `AccountDetails` which would be full of empty strings.

You probably need to change `getCustDetails` in your DAL to return an instance of `AccountDetails` instead of an `IEnumerable` of it, and set `obj1` to that:

```
AccountDetails obj1 = obj.getCustDetails(customerId);
```

In your DAL:

```
public AccountDetails getCustDetails(string customerId)
{
    //Pulls customer information for selected customer 
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
    var custRecords = from account in doc.Descendants("acct")
                      let acct = account.Element("acct")
                      where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                      select new AccountDetails
                      {
                          Fname = (string)account.Attribute("fname").Value,
                          Lname = (string)account.Attribute("lname").Value,
                          Ssn = (string)account.Attribute("ssn").Value,
                          Dob = (string)account.Attribute("dob").Value,
                          Custid = (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value
                      };


    return custRecords.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Note that if your DAL can't find an account with the specified `customerId`, it will return a `null` (which is the default value of a class). You will need to check the return value against null before using if you do not want a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown in such an eventuality.